# Manager Package remover permission object standard

Tags: managed-package, standard-objects, permission-sets, remove

I have a question here. I have a manager package and when I upload to some org my permission sets no longer have permissions for standard objects, does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Image Dev
[image]

Image other org
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't package standard object permissions. Packaging semantics of Profiles and Permission Sets are documented in the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_perm_sets_profile_setttings.htm):

> Do they include standard object permissions?
> No. Also, you can’t include object permissions for a custom object in a master-detail relationship where the master is a standard object.

Standard object permissions are silently ignored during the packaging process.

Comment: Thanks David for the clarification